# neo4j return map of properties+ID

Tags: dictionary, neo4j, cypher

I want to get back a map (dictionary) of the properties of my nodes in cypher along with the ID of the nodes. I have the following code that does not work:

```
match (n:person) 
with n limit 5
with  properties(n)+oldID:ID(n) as info
return info
```

This does not create a single dictionary with the properties and the ID. I have tried different formats but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return the properties along with the id like this :

```
MATCH (n:Person)
RETURN n{.*, oldID: id(n)} AS info
LIMIT 5
```

Result :

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"info"                                             │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"born":1964,"name":"Keanu Reeves","oldID":1}      │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"born":1967,"name":"Carrie-Anne Moss","oldID":2}  │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"born":1961,"name":"Laurence Fishburne","oldID":3}│
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"born":1960,"name":"Hugo Weaving","oldID":4}      │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"born":1967,"name":"Lilly Wachowski","oldID":5}   │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Useful resource for learning Map projections https://neo4j.com/developer-blog/a-comprehensive-guide-to-cypher-map-projection/

Comment: I like this better than my answer. I tried too hard to stay close to the original question :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could just do

```
match (n:person) 
with n limit 5
with  {props:properties(n), oldID:ID(n)} as info
return info
```